# How may I convert a JavaScript [object String] to HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am making a sortable list using the *SortableJS* [library](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable). The library makes all HTML elements inside a specified id=""-tag draggable and sortable. For example:

```
<ul id="items">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
var el = document.getElementById('items');
var sortable = Sortable.create(el);
```

I am using JavaScript to generate the HTML elements and wish to make the id dynamic. The following works as intended:

```
// Several list items are generated and wrapped in this <div>
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.id = 'foo';
Sortable.create(foo, options);
```

When I attempt to make the id dynamic it throws an error:

```
// Several list items are generated and wrapped in this <div>
// An input exists with id="userGivenListName"
var listName = document.getElementById('userGivenListName').value;
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.id = listName;
Sortable.create(listName, options);
```

> Uncaught Sortable: `el` must be an HTMLElement, not [object String]

When I `console.log(wrapper.id);` after typing "foo" into my form it returns the exact same as when I `console.log(wrapper.id);` in the above, working code.

I have attempted to add single-quotes with no success:

```
wrapper.id = "'" + listName + "'";
```

Comment: There a reason you dont use the created element like documentation suggests? `Sortable.create(wrapper, options)` - right now you providing a String instead of HTMLElement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML do this:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

In Javascript do this:

```
// Default SortableJS
import Sortable from 'sortablejs';

// create list dynamically
var id=123; 
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = `
<ul id="${id}">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
`;
Sortable.create(document.getElementById(id), {});

// create another list dynamically
id=124; 
document.getElementById('container2').innerHTML = `
<ul id="${id}">
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
`;
Sortable.create(document.getElementById(id), {});
```

See Stackblitz-Project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nlyfcw?file=index.js

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var listName = document.getElementById('userGivenListName').value;
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.setAttribute("id", listName);
Sortable.create(listName, options);
```

Comment: Sorry but this throws the same error, David's answer solved my problem.